# Mudar distancia no eixo x - Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou montando um grafico utilizando a biblioteca matplotlib do Python mas o resultando não ficou bom! Os nomes do angulo x não está sendo visivel. 
Segue imagem [image: Imagem Grafico]

Código:

```html
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Meu Décimo oitavo Programa
#Trabalhando com  MySQL and Python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import MySQLdb

host = "meuhost"
user = "meuuser"
password = "minhasenha"
db = "meubd"
port = 3306

con = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,password,db,port)

valory = []
valorx = []
mycursor = con.cursor()
distance = 5
mycursor.execute("select programa, count(num_doc) as Total from pcrs group by programa")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    valorx.append(x[0])
    valory.append(x[1])

plt.scatter(valorx,valory)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Antes do `plt.show()` adicione:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

o valor 30 significa o ângulo que os labels estarão orientados com relação a horizantal. Valor este que pode ser modificado.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!